# JavaFX: Change text color of textarea

Tags: css, javafx

Alright so I can't get this to work at all. I've checked the CSS analyzer in the scene builder and I came to the conclusion that the way to change the text color in a textarea is something similar to this:`

```
.text-area .text {
    -fx-fill: #1e88e5;
    -fx-font-size: 32px;
}`
```

Problem is that the color doesn't change nor does the font size. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Use -fx-text-fill: color, and put what color you wish.

Comment: I tried it but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
.text-area   {
    -fx-text-fill: #1e88e5;
    -fx-font-size: 32px;
}
```

**Update**: the Style class `text-area` doesn't have a descendant named `text`. it has an immediate child named `scroll-pane` and a decendant named `content` .for more information see: [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#textarea)

Comment: That worked, thanks! Strange, why doesn't it work the way I did it? Any ideas?